# Bitbucket Webhook plugin for Jenkins - differentiate between branches

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, bitbucket, bcbsn

We use Jenkins and have the Bitbucket plugin installed. We've got multiple repos and use webhooks for lots of jobs coming from our `foo` repo. No problems there, the jobs go off without a hitch. Now however we want to start running a couple jobs via webhook from our `bar` repo.

#### The Problem

The default behavior here is that as soon as we attach a webhook to `bar`, commits to either repo will trigger any job with polling. I know we can hardcode in logic in each job to either only build when commits match a certain pattern, or ignore any commits matching a pattern.

Given the number of jobs we have that currently use polling this would be insanely unideal to have to code in to make it backwards compatible, not to mention potentially doing this again if we start running unit tests on even more repos in the future.

#### The Ideal Solution

I'm hoping I might be missing some way to differentiate between commits made from `foo` vs `bar` on the Bitbucket side, rather than needing to change anything in each Jenkins job. Ideally, there's some way to change the webhook so each repo gets its own url. Does this, or some other blanket solution, exist? (I will accept "no" as an answer if that's the case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it is now possible to configure the webhook on per-repo basis:

https://mohamicorp.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOC/pages/381419546/Configuring+Webhook+To+Jenkins+for+Bitbucket+Bitbucket+Branch+Source+Plugin

Answer (score 2):

You could:

- prune your branches. (guessing you'd have done this by now if feasible.)
- implement Jenkinsfile, a code-driven pipeline,
  and simply remove the jenkinsfile from the branches you don't want
  built or triggered by SCM-polling.

Answer (score 1):

One could use [SCM polling](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/PollSCM+Plugin) and specify different branches that need to be polled.

Comment: As I stated in my question, while this is a valid approach on a smaller scale, this is impractical for my case, where black/whitelisting branches would be a monumental task.

Answer (score 0):

So... I had this issue and solved it by making sure I passed the pull request ID to the Jenkins job and the Branch ID from Pull Request. I've attached a screen shot. [image]

And this as well:

[image]

you can *absolutely* control what Jenkins pulls from your SCM w/the proper configurations - these should get you there.

Also: I have polling disabled - you really don't want to use polling as it is expensive - configure a BitBucket PullRequest plugin to call your Jenkins job upon creation as you are doing and you shouldn't *need* to poll, although I don't know that particular plugin... this one is great:

https://github.com/tomasbjerre/pull-request-notifier-for-bitbucket